# ASP.Net Core 2 - Using a DBContext having defaultConnectionString from appsettings

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to create a basic CRUD in ASP.Net Core 2 with EntityFrameworkCore.

My **appsettings.json** file is like this-

```
"DefaultConnection": "server=localhost; port=3306; database=inventory_management; user=root; password=;"
```

I want to read connection from this file. What I have done is -
In **Startup.cs** - Startup

```
        //Configuration = configuration;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

and then in ConfigureServices-

```
services.AddDbContext<InventoryManagementDbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevelopConnection")));
```

Then in controller, I am trying this-

[image]

So, I am getting this error-

[image]

What do I need to do to solve this error?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow your `DbContext` to be injected into your controller as follows:

```
public class YourController
{
    InventoryManagementDbContext _context;

    // Dependency Injection
    public YourController(InventoryManagementDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Action Index()
    {
        _context.Employee.Add(...);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I call ensureCreated in there? Can you please help?

Comment: This post might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958318/where-should-i-put-database-ensurecreated#36958610

Comment: Thank you very much